# Android layout_below not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to position my RecyclerView so that it is below my AppBarLayout, however the layout_below attribute is not being recognised by android studio? It does not show in the auto-complete.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment.SearchFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_light"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: use Linearlayout or Relativelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your layout as below. Used `LinearLayout` with property `android:orientation="vertical"` instead of `FrameLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment.SearchFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_light"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Search..."
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout_Below exists in the relativeLayout , if you want to get access to that , you may need to switch to RelativeLayout or Alternativaly use linear layout if you want to put views one under the other by setting the orientation to vertical .

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. A RecyclerView should never go underneath an AppBarLayout. What you should do is ensure that there is sufficient margin between the RecyclerView and the AppbarLayout

Answer (score 0):

you need the layout like ConstraintLayout, RelativeLayout and LinearLayout.

example:

ConstraintLayout :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_light"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Search..."
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

RelativeLayout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_light"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Search..."
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

LinearLayout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_light"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Search..."
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />


    </LinearLayout>
 
    
    </FrameLayout>
```